# 3x3 grid with a wider middle column that has its top and bottom cells shorter without changing the height of the cells on the sides

Tags: css-grid

I'm trying to make the middle column wider with its middle cell longer on the expense of the top and bottom cells, without changing the height of the cells on the sides.[image: preview grid]

I got close enough by making the middle column wider, but I made the top and bottom cells of the middle column shorter by making their rows shorter, which's not what I want and can't figure out how not to.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 6fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: ". . ." ". . ." ". . .";
  grid-gap: 4px;
  height: calc(100vh - 1px);
  width: calc(100% - 1px);
}

.cell {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
<div class="cell">1</div>
<div class="cell">2</div>
<div class="cell">3</div>
<div class="cell">4</div>
<div class="cell">5</div>
<div class="cell">6</div>
<div class="cell">7</div>
<div class="cell">8</div>
<div class="cell">9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

one way to do it, is to divide the grid info more rows and columns and set the position and area of each cell/div using grid lines.
I tripled each row and column, so now we have 10 row lines and column lines instead of 4, and then you can set where you want each cell/div to be on the grid with the [`grid-row`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row) and [`grid-column`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column) properties, the value should be `<on which line to start> / <on which line to end>`

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: ". . . . . . . . ." ". . . . . . . . ." ". . . . . . . . .";
  grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(9, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 4px;
  height: calc(100vh - 1px);
  width: calc(100% - 1px);
}
.cell:nth-child(1) {
  grid-row: 1/4;
  grid-column: 1/2;
}
.cell:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: 1/2;
  grid-column: 2/9;
}
.cell:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: 1/4;
  grid-column: 9/10;
}
.cell:nth-child(4) {
  grid-row: 4/7;
  grid-column: 1/2;
}
.cell:nth-child(5) {
  grid-row: 2/9;
  grid-column: 2/9;
}
.cell:nth-child(6) {
  grid-row: 4/7;
  grid-column: 9/10;
}
.cell:nth-child(7) {
  grid-row: 7/10;
  grid-column: 1/2;
}
.cell:nth-child(8) {
  grid-row: 9/10;
  grid-column: 2/9;
}
.cell:nth-child(9) {
  grid-row: 7/10;
  grid-column: 9/10;
}
.cell {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
<div class="cell">1</div>
<div class="cell">2</div>
<div class="cell">3</div>
<div class="cell">4</div>
<div class="cell">5</div>
<div class="cell">6</div>
<div class="cell">7</div>
<div class="cell">8</div>
<div class="cell">9</div>
</div>
```